# Как работает многопоточность java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Объясните пожалуйста буквально на пальцах, простыми словами, как работает многопоточность в java.. Есть вопросы на которые я не могу найти ТОЧНЫЙ ответ, из-за чего возникает расплывчатое понимание материала.
Вопрос такой, у нас есть два объекта разных типов с переопределенными методами run(), и один поток Thread, можно ли их поместить в выполнение одного потока, и могут ли они они исполняться именно одновременно? или эти два метода в потоке будут попеременно выполняться?

И вообще, объясните краткими словами тему)про всякие методы wait() и notify() читал.

Comment: 1 поток - одно одновременное выполнение. Поток не может выполнять параллельно несколько действий.
По сути поток(нить) - это цепочка **последовательных** действий.
Каша в вашей голове рождается от непонимания более простых вещей =)
wait и notify - забудьте пока не поймете концепцию многопоточности, а когда поймете - придет осознание синхронизаций. Вникайте так сказать https://habr.com/ru/post/164487/

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что в одном потоке может находиться несколько объектов?

Comment: Объекты к потокам не имеют никакого отношения, вы изначально неправильно понимаете многопоточность. поток - это "очередь" команд, ни больше ни меньше. Как я уже говорил неоднократно - java не язык для новичка, именно потому что там всё это классы или объекты(на самом деле нет, но преподносится всё именно так).

Comment: смысле в java нету классов и объектов?

Comment: объясните пожалуйста в двух словах, без "это не язык для новичка", в гугл тоже отправлять не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Метод run() тянется из интерфейса Runnable(), который реализуется классом Thread.

Thread - это и есть класс потока.

Метод run() - это тот метод который начнет выполняться при старте потока. Как только все действия описанные в методе run() выполнится - поток завершится.

Внутри метода run() вы можете делать все что хотите. Создавать любые объекты, выполнять с ними любые действия - все это будет происходить в вашем отдельном потоке. Можете создавать и стартовать другие потоки - все что вы опишите в них будет происходить в отдельных параллельных потоках.

Потоки применяют либо чтоб ускорить выполнение каких либо действий, либо если можно какие-то действия выполнять отдельно от основного потока (например построение отчета, который долго считается, или отправка писем или ...)

Поток можно создать так

```
 public class MyThread extends Thread{
     @Override
     public void run(){
        ...
     }
 }

 //Тогда создание экземпляра будет выглядеть так
 ...

 Thread myThread = new MyThread();
 myThread.start(); //запуск потока

 ...
```

или так

```
 public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
     @Override
     public void run(){
        ...
     }
 }

 //Тогда создание экземпляра будет выглядеть так
 ...

 Thread myThread = new MyThread( new MyRunnable() );
 myThread.start(); //запуск потока

 ...
```

Comment: А потокобезопасность где? ни слова нету =)

Comment: Предположим два каких-то  метода помещенные в run() будут выполняться попеременно имитируя многопоточность, или эти два метода будут последовательно выполняться?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а про нее никто и не спрашивал :) просили кратко...

Comment: И я могу поместить в один поток несколько методов run()?

Comment: @Ivan что вы имеете ввиду  "попеременно выполняться"? Метод run() может быть только один. Как вы себе представляете в классе два метода с одинаковыми названиями и входными параметрами?

Comment: @Ivan если вам надо чтоб методы параллельно выполнялись. Создаете два потока

Comment: @Ivan по очереди

Comment: @Ivan вообще тема очень обширная, и не сказал бы что очень простая, чтоб вложить ее в один вопрос. Вы придумайте пример, где нужно асинхронное выполнение, и попробуйте реализовать, используя книги и обучающие статьи. И если что-то не будет получаться, то выкладывайте пример своего кода, с описанием что вы хотели сделать, и что получилось не так как вы задумывали.

Comment: Я правильно понял что, все действия в потоке сугубо последовательно выполняются, но программа может перепрыгивать выполнение с одного потока на другой? Для того чтобы метод run() выполнился полностью 1 итерация сверху до низу (как происходит 1 итерация в зацикленном Run()???), используют синхронизацию, чтобы выполнение метода run() не приостанавливалось посередине. Правильно я понимаю? Управление потоками возможно через ExecutorService, правильно? Зачем нужен Семафор и что это такое?

Comment: Не пытайтесь охватить весь материал сразу, без практики у вас в голове будет полная каша.

Comment: Изучайте по мере необходимости применения. Мало знать кучу технологий и патернов, самое главное правильно их применять, иначе это ведет только к неоправданному усложнению программы.

Comment: Мне нужно отправлять на сервер запросы, и получать ответы,считать время выполнения запроса, 2 запроса в 3 секунды. Каждые 5 минут количество запросов увеличивается на 1, время через которое отправляются запросы остаётся неизменным, т.е 3 запроса в 3 секунды и т.д. Как это все реализовать?

Comment: А где вы здесь нашли многопоточность?

Comment: Это можно сделать без потоков? Как?

Comment: Вам нужно три метода которые будут это реализовывать. 1 - цикл с таймером, 2 - цикл который вызывает ваш 3 метод с логикой которую вы хотите выполнять. Если нужна помощь - создайте проект на github, и опишите что вы хотите сделать в файле README.md  и киньте ссылку на проект.

Comment: @Ivan "используют синхронизацию, чтобы выполнение метода run() не приостанавливалось посередине. Правильно я понимаю?"
Неправильно. Синхронизация реализуется через приостановку, и чтобы не приостанавливалось посередине, синхронизацию надо отключить, если это возможно.

Comment: @rfq новые данные как я понял синхронизацию: это мы можем блокировать выполнение метода, чтобы его мог выполнить не прерываясь только один поток...Я прав?

Comment: есть 2 механизма синхронизации: а) по доступу к общим данным, если один поток выполнил synchronized, все остальные при попытке выполнить synchronized будут задержаны, чтобы не мешать первому. б) если поток успешно выполнил `synchronized`, но увидел, что предназначавшиеся ему данные еще не готовы, он выполняет метод `Object.wait()`. Тот, кто запишет данные, должен выполнить `Object.notify()`.

Comment: @Z.John , у тебя есть электронная почта?

Answer (score 0):

Поток - это последовательность исполняемых команд. В Jav'e - команд, размещенных в методе `run()`. Поэтому один поток - один метод `run()`. Для двух методов `run()` нужны два потока. Или один, но с другим метолом `run()`:

```
public void run() {
  object1.run(); 
  object2.run();
}
```

то есть, выполняющий их последовательно. Попеременно в одном потоке исполнять разные методы технически невоэможно.

Методологически поток - это виртуальный процессор. Сейчас с помощью технологии виртуализации можно один компьютер разбить на несколько виртуальных машин и на каждую поставить собственную операционную систему. Аналогично, аппаратный процессор можно разбить на несколько виртуальных процессоров - потоков, и на каждом запустить свою программу. Для этого есть техника переключения процессора с одного потока на другой. Но техники переключения потока  с одного метода на другой не сделали, потому что нет смысла.

Comment: "Попеременно в одном потоке исполнять разные методы технически невоэможно." - тогда в чем смысл многопоточности? Я думал что система автоматически переключает выполнение между void run(), и потоками object.run() object2.run()... Что если выполнение object.run() слишком длительное??

Comment: смысл в том что а) каждый процессор (ядро в понимании железячника) исполняет свой поток и б) поток может покидать процессор на время, позволяя исполняться большому числу потоков.

Comment: "Что если выполнение object.run() слишком длительное?" - ну значит исполнение `object2.run()` откладывается, надо было запускать его в собственном потоке.

Comment: потоки именно одновременно выполняются конкретно в java-машине? дословно одновременно, или все таки попеременно? Какой смысл тогда Семафоров?

Comment: максимальное число одновременно выполняемых потоков равно числу доступных процессоров - и в java-машине тоже, так как она использует для многопоточности механизмы операционной системы. Семафоры нужны для организации взаимодействий между потоками. Если потоки не взаимодействуют, ничто не мешает им выполняться полностью параллельно.